# Use Javamail for accessing Microsoft Exchange mailboxes (IMAP, MS Exchange)

Tags: java, authentication, exchange-server, jakarta-mail, imap

I need to connect to a Microsoft Exchange Server through IMAPS JavaMail. First, I got the:

```
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

exception in my debugger.

Then, I disabled some authentication protocols:

```
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");
```

This is the new exception I'm getting (I've attached the whole log):

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG: disable AUTH=PLAIN
DEBUG: disable AUTH=NTLM
DEBUG: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "host.domain.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE  NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=host.domain.com, user=user@domain.com,  password=<non-null>
A1 LOGIN user@domain.com password
A1 NO LOGIN failed.
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "host.domain.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=host.domain.com, user=user@domain.com, password=<non-null>
A1 LOGIN user@domain.com password
A1 NO LOGIN failed.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:660)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at ConnectMail.connectMail(ConnectMail.java:63)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Now I'm getting the "NO LOGIN failed" Exception.

This is my full code:

```
Properties imapProps = new Properties();
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", "993");
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");
imapProps.setProperty("username", "user@domain.com");   
imapProps.setProperty("password", "password");

String host = "host.domain.com";
int port = Integer.parseInt("993");

Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("user@domain.com", "password");
    }
};

session = Session.getInstance(imapProps, authenticator);

session.setDebug(true);

Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

store.connect(host, "user@domain.com", "password");
```

Comment: Your code is absolutely correct (perhaps some lines not needed at all - authenticator example because you are using username and password in your connect - but do not worry) it works within our exchange environment. Yo need to talk to your Exchange SysAdmin because the problem should come from that side.

Comment: Sorry for the late update. Yes, this code was correct. The issue was with the Exchange Server. This code is correct if anyone is planning to use it..

Comment: Can you please describe the issue that your Exchange Server was having when you received this error.  Thanks!

Comment: It was simple, I was provided with the wrong credentials. @ClickerTweeker

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a newer version of JavaMail that supports NTLM authentication.  The latest version is [1.5.1](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Also, see this list of [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 1):

It will workout if the username and the mail id both are same.

For example: system username is john and mail id john@test.com

IMAP is try to login the mail id using the username "john" from john@test.com, if the user id is differ it will not login.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your own Authenticator

```
public class ExchangeAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    String username;
    String password;

    public ExchangeAuthenticator(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username= username;
        this.password= password;
    }

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
}
```

and in your code add

```
session = Session.getInstance(props,new ExchangeAuthenticator(username, password));
```