# How to validate the login with JavaMail?

Tags: android, email, exception, authentication, jakarta-mail

I am trying to create a app for android, I am using javamail, but I am getting some trouble: How can I check if the email and password are correct ?
If someone put an email e a password incorrects is it possible to show "email or password incorrets" before send the email ?
All examples I see don't do it, and I don't find a way to get the exception... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a login class where user type a login and the password ... then they press the login button ...

also ive got a class called ReadMails where i created a method called checkForErrors (this method is called when login button is pressed)

```
public int checkForErrors() {
    try {
        store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(mailServer, username, password);
        inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        Message[] result = inbox.getMessages();
        return 0;
    } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 1;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 2;
    }
}
```

i call this method in login class , if it returns **0** i know that everything went OK ...
if it returns **1** "AuthenticationFailedException" is thrown , so i know that user typed wrong password or login ... and so on ...

also u might be interested in this [Use Javamail for accessing Microsoft Exchange mailboxes (IMAP, MS Exchange)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066802/use-javamail-for-accessing-microsoft-exchange-mailboxes-imap-ms-exchange) topic ...

Comment: this part of your code is necessary to check the email : 
inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message[] result = inbox.getMessages();
 and also I using smtps, should I change "imaps" for "smtp" ?

Comment: no its not necessary ... and yes , if you are using smpt you have to change it to smpt but first you have to create your own smpt session if havent do it yet ...

Comment: instead of imapSession I'm using my session and in the place of "mailServer" my host (gmail), but now i'm receiving an exception (NoSuchProviderException)

Comment: What do you mean 'my session'? Unless you're writing a JavaMail provider you can't just provide your own session class.

Comment: no, that is not a class but a session that a had put the properties and the authentication, it works, because I can send emais with it, but now I need to first check the information of the user and then try to send the email

Comment: Just use Transport.connect to see if it succeeds, then Transport.close.  You don't need to send a message to test that the login information is correct.